# Tridion 2011 SP1 broker database resource max out and tokens timesout on mass publishing

Tags: 2011, publishing, broker, 2011-sp1

Please be kind as this is my first question on stack exchange.

When we are mass publishing to our broker databases, especially on mass publishing, the server resource max's out and then starts causing timeout issues to both our website and CMS.

The error I can retrieve from the CMS server is below, please note I have hidden the database name and user name with `[*****]`.

```
A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_TRUSTEES_GETTRUSTEETOKEN". Cannot open database "[*****]" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '[*****]'. 
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing 
Errorcode: 0 
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
StackTrace Information Details: 
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) 
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) 
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetConnection() 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetStoredProcedureCommand(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.SystemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ISystemDataMapper.GetAccessToken(String username, IEnumerable`1 directoryGroupMemberships) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets) 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor() 
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.DeploymentFeedbackHandler.DoWork()
```

Has anyone else come across this issue or similar before?

Is it possible that a memory leak is causing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Steve. Can you share more information like is it happening only while doing mass publishing? What is mass publishing - Multiple Components at once or a Single Structure Group with hundreds of pages?
The error on the high level suggests that it is because the User Credentials have been given wrong values in the cd_storage_config.xml file, is your publishing to Broker DB working at all from the same publication for which you are getting error?

Comment: Hi,
By mass publishing I am referring to both single structure groups and multiple pages / components in different transactions. Publishing small amounts of items is not an issue and the error isn't isolated to a single publication. The problem either occurs over a week of publishing small transactions or during a "mass" publish.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a known issue and you should try applying following Hotfix: [CD_2011.1.1.84879 - Cumulative hotfix](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx)

Try after applying this hot fix and let us know your findings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We have scheduled some time in next week to try this and I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: if it works out, do not forget to mark it as Answer and upvote ;)

Comment: I went to apply this hotfix and realised it is for HR1 only. We have SDL Tridion 2011 SP1-HR2 installed and therefore this hotfix already applied.

Comment: You should go and raise this with support, as there may be chances that this might not be there in HR2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a Tridion issue.  The error "Login failed for user '[*****]'" is coming from the SQL client when it tries to open a connection to the database. If this only occurs during mass publishing then perhaps it's an overloaded SQL server which is refusing logins.

Ask your DBA to investigate the cause of the login failures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately our DBA is not available, so I am hoping there is something I can do in the meantime to hold back committing deployment.

I have been investigating the window and worker size in cd_deployer_conf.xml. We currently have the values set to WindowSize="40" Workers="10". The CD architecture is 2 deployers (one on each web server) writing to 2 broker databases (one each) on the database server, both using the same username.  Every server has 2 logical cores, 64-bit machines with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I have reduced the WindowSize to 20 and this has made the database server more stable, but I have a feeling this is just masking the underlying issue. I have an open support ticket with SDL and I will update this thread if we come to a definitive resolution.